# User Roles and Permission in CodeIgniter 2.1.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, acl

I am using this version of **codeigniter 2.1.4** and I want to add user roles and permission. I am totally new for this framework I have done this in *Zend* but I am not able to find any library in codeigniter. I am also confused with **Hooks**.

Anybody will explain me what the purpose of hooks in a layman language. and also about the library with a small example with the same version so that it will be easy to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: CI 3.0 should be coming soon, so I would tentatively say don't invest too much time in 2.1.4 right now. also hooks are ways to run code at specific points of the internal CI workings. ie. precontroller, postcontroller. rather than editing CI code, hooks inject your code in.

Comment: Can we relate hooks with acl ? @Andrew Brown

Comment: i have no idea what ACL is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have experience with the Zend ACL, why not use it in your CodeIgniter project? ([Link](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/adding-zend-acl-to-codeigniter/))

Just set up your roles, resources, and permissions in your "MY_Controller.php" file so they're available to all your controllers. Also set up your user in MY_Controller (e.g. $this->theUser) for the same reason.

Set up classes for your resources in your Libraries folder that "implements Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface" and a "User" class for your user that "implements Zend_Acl_Role_Interface".

After setting up the ACL in MY_Controller, retrieve role(s) for the user from your database and add them to your user:

```
$roles = $this->theUser->getRoles(); // get the assigned role(s) for the user (array)
$acl->addRole($this->theUser, $roles); // then apply them to the user
```

With that done, I typically put something like the following at the top of each controller:

```
if ( !$this->acl->isAllowed($this->theUser, 'article', 'modify') ) {
    redirect( '/home', 'refresh' ); // go back home
    exit;
}
```

Don't forget, you can even set up dynamic assertions (i.e. implements Zend_Acl_Assert_Interface) if a permission to a resource requires some logic. I typically put assertion classes immediately following their related resource class.

Comment: Thanks Scotty I understand you are trying say include Zend ACL libraries. Will you please explain me step by step. I have never include any library to any framework. Here you are saying I can Include Zend library.

Comment: Correct. The link showing how to integrate Zend ACL into CodeIgniter is http://lucdebrouwer.nl/adding-zend-acl-to-codeigniter/

Comment: Those instructions seem a little old, but still good. By the way, I don't use anything after line 17 in the Zacl.php file shown on that page since my roles, resources, and permissions aren't that complicated. I just have a single "role" field in my user table with comma-separated roles, then use PHP explode() to create the array of roles for $acl->addRole(). Please vote up the solution, by the way!

Comment: Guide me Scotty how to Vote up for your solution... anyways you have solved my problem. :-)

Comment: It says Vote Up requires 15 Reputation... Now ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ion_Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), it is an authentication library with a system of user roles. Should be easier for you to create permissions in your code.

This is only my 2-cents but Hooks are somehow similar to an event-driven approach. This means that they will be triggered at particular times in your code.
In the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html), you can see that CI has 7 hooks ready. Thus, you can inject any script of yours at those 7 moments.

Let's say that you can add a script during the hook `pre_controller` that checks for the user's browser's language, so that in all your controllers you already know the language to use.

Note that ion_auth also supports hooks.